# List<?> or List<Object>

Tags: java, generics

I have a method whose argument should be "a List of anything". The method will not modify the contents of the List. Is it more correct to define this method as

```
void foo(List<?> list) {
}
```

or

```
void foo(List<Object> list) {
}
```

and what exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer, using `List<?>` will allow you to accept something like `List<String>` while using `List<Object>` won't.

This is discussed in the official generics trail, [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

> [...] here is a naive attempt at writing it using generics (and the new for loop syntax):
>
> ```
>    void printCollection(Collection<Object> c) {
>        for (Object e : c) {
>            System.out.println(e);
>        }
>    }
> ```
>
> The problem is that this new version is much less useful than the old one. Whereas the old code could be called with any kind of collection as a parameter, the new code only takes `Collection<Object>`, which, as we've just demonstrated, is not a supertype of all kinds of collections!
>   **So what is the supertype of all kinds of collections? It's written `Collection<?>` (pronounced "collection of unknown"), that is, a collection whose element type matches anything.** It's called a wildcard type for obvious reasons. We can write:
>
> ```
>    void printCollection(Collection<?> c) {
>        for (Object e : c) {
>            System.out.println(e);
>        }
>    }
> ```
>
> and now, we can call it with any type of collection.

Answer (score 5):

The `List<Object>` has parameterized type `Object` which essentially means that you can add **all** objects in the list.

However, `List<?>` means that is **a list of unknowns**. As long as you're not going to add anything to the list, it's essentially the same as `List<Object>` but you will have to worry with circumstances as follows:

```
List<?> unknownList = new ArrayList<String>();
unknownList.add(new Object()); //Compilation error.
```

The `?` (in this case) means that you can only add values of `String` or is subtype of `String`.

If you're just going to iterate through the list and retrieve values, `List<?>` and `List<Object>` is essentially the same.

More info [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: You can't add anything other than null to a List<?>

Comment: If you're using a list of unknowns, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The two are quite different

```
void foo(List<?> list)
```

means you expect a list of something but you haven't specified what it is

```
void foo(List<Object> list)
```

Says you expect the list passed is a list of object, so if you try to pass a List it will not be accepted (as opposed to the first declaration)

A common mistake is to assume that `List<String>` is a *subtype* so to speak of `List<Object>` this is not the case even though String is a suptype of Object.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the list, than `List<?>` is more suitable.

This way you can pass e. g. `List<String>` and `List<BigInteger>` to your method.

Answer (score 0):

You need `void foo(List<?> list)`, or else you won't be able, for example, to pass in a `List<String>`.

If you use `void foo(List<Object> list)`, then you can only pass in `List<Object>`.

This is because, in Java, generics are not [covariant](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html): `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

Section 3 and 4 of this tutorial should answer your question:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

Quoting from the tutorial:

> In general, if Foo is a subtype (subclass or subinterface) of Bar, and G is some generic type declaration, it is not the case that G<Foo> is a subtype of G<Bar> ....
>
> ... Collection<Object>, which, as we’ve just demonstrated, is not a supertype of all kinds of collections!
> So what is the supertype of all kinds of collections? It’s written Collection<?> (pronounced “collection of unknown”) , that is, a collection whose element type matches anything.

However, under the **strict** assumption that the method foo will leave the collection unmodified, there should be no difference in implementation.